# A reduce function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, abstraction, higher-order-functions

I'm studying Javascript using Marijn Haverbeke's book *Eloquent JavaScript* and didn't understand the following example:

```
function reduce(combine, base, array) {
    forEach(array, function (element) {
        base = combine(base, element);
    });
    return base;
}

function add(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function sum(numbers) {
    return reduce(add, 0, numbers);
}
```

The `forEach` function is one he introduces earlier in the book, which is the following:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        action(array[i]);
}
```

Now, back to the `reduce` function, what I don't understand is why, in the `sum` function, `0` is passed as `base` to `reduce`. Isn't that weird? Let's say I try to run `sum([1,2,3])`... wouldn't it look something like `0 = add(0,1)` in its first loop? I don't get it.

Comment: It's not `0 = add(0, 1)`, it's just that the variable (i.e. `base`) is being assigned to a new value. It's not weird at all, because you're allowed to do so in JavaScript. It's not like this is Erlang or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding it is putting the sum to `base` only. So it is getting incremented on every loop.

`base = combine(base, element)`

This statement first computes `combine(base, element)` and assigns it to `base`. Its not comparing `0` and `add(0, 1)`. So for the next iteration, `base` would have the sum for all the previous values.

**EDITED**

Suppose, you call `reduce(combine, 0, [10, 22, 7, 5])`. Loop will be iterated as

```
Iteration           base          element
1                   0             10
```

After computing `add(base, element)`, `base` is set to 10. So for the next iteration, its value is 10.

```
1                   10            22
```

After computing `add(base, element)`, `base` is set to 32. So for the next iteration, its value is 32.

```
1                   32            7
```

After computing `add(base, element)`, `base` is set to 39. So for the next iteration, its value is 39.

```
1                   39            5
```

After computing `add(base, element)`, `base` is set to 44. Since there are no more elements left, the answer is 44.

Comment: I'm still confused... When the function `add` is called, the value `0` is assigned to `base`. From this point on, shouldn't `base` be substituted for `0` whenever it's invoked inside the function?

`base` is pointing to an address in the memory, right? How does the JavaScript engine know when it should use the value stored in the memory and when it should just "point" to it? In other words, why does the first `base` not get substituted by `0`?

Comment: _base_ is not an address, its just a value. It is getting substituted by `0` for the first iteration but later it is incremented by the value of each element
Edited my answer for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

base is the variable that will contain the sum of all elements. It's normal that it starts with 0.

It's not : 0 = add(0,1)

but rather : base will contain the sum of previous value of base and 1

Answer (score 1):

Remember as well that the content on the right side of the equals sign is evaluated first.  So,

```
base = combine(base, element)
```

is taking the result of `combine(base, element)` and assigning it to the variable `base` (which now overwrites what `base` was previously assigned to).